# C++ simulate pressing of equal sign (=) and question mark (?)

Tags: c++, simulation, virtual-keyboard

Having some problems with simulating a keypress of equal sign (=) and question mark (?).
I figured if there's no virtual key code for those two, I should combine key presses and releases as this guy did with Ctrl-V:
http://batchloaf.wordpress.com/2012/10/18/simulating-a-ctrl-v-keystroke-in-win32-c-or-c-using-sendinput/

my code for "=" (SHIFT + "+"):

```
INPUT ip;

ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
ip.ki.wScan = 0; // hardware scan code for key
ip.ki.time = 0;
ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

ip.ki.wVk = VK_LSHIFT;
ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

// Press the "+" key
ip.ki.wVk = VK_OEM_PLUS;
ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

// Release the "+" key
ip.ki.wVk = VK_OEM_PLUS;
ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

// Release the "Shift" key
ip.ki.wVk = VK_LSHIFT;
ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
```

it outputs the "+" sign. I need it to work on, preferably any windows OS, but at least Windows XP (not sure if it makes a difference).

Thank you.

Comment: You are not supposed to call `SendInput()` 4 times with `nInputs=1`. You should call it 1 time with `nInputs=4` and give it an array of 4 `INPUT` structs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `=` character is the non-capitalized character on the `=`/`+` key, while `+` is the capitalized character. Thus, to output an equals sign, simply use the (badly named) `VK_OEM_PLUS` virtual key code.

Comment: thank you! works as you said. and for the question mark? I tried VK_OEM_2 and the output is '4'

Comment: oups, sorry, the capitalized VK_OEM_2 did the '?'. Thank you